# run the tcl script with its inputs on one line

Tags: tcl

i have one script for this script manual input i am giving.

step 1:  tclsh /india/ksantosh/innovus/scripts/def_file.tcl 
step 2: it will ask    "def_file.def"

step3: it will ask offset_x value   "20"

step 4: it will ask for offset_y value   "20"

step 5: it will execute the script and generate *modified   "def_file*.modified.def"

but I want to execute this in one line to save time
tclsh /india/proj_n16_hbm2etigris/n16_hbm2etigris/be/work/ksantosh/innovus/scripts/def_file.tcl  def_file.def  20  20

It should work like /india/proj_n16_hbm2etigris/n16_hbm2etigris/be/work/ksantosh/innovus/scripts/def_file.tcl<input_def> <outputs_def>  <x_offset> <y_offset> 
If output-file is not given then it should be<input_def>_modifed.def

where def_file.tcl have this code

```
puts "Enter input file name:"
flush stdout
gets stdin filename

set input_def [open $filename r]

# create output file name based on input file name
set output_filename [file rootname $filename]_modified.[file extension $filename]
set output_file [open $output_filename w]
puts "Enter offset_x:"
flush stdout
gets stdin offset_x

puts "Enter offset_y:"
flush stdout
gets stdin offset_y


set star *


while {[gets $input_def line] >=0} {
        if {[ string match {UNITS DISTANCE MICRONS*} $line]} {
        set Micron_Unit [lindex [split $line] 3]
        set Micron_Unit [format "%.1f" $Micron_Unit]
        }
        if {[string match {*ROUTED*} $line] || [string match {*FIXED*} $line] || [string match {*COVER*} $line] || [string match {*SHIELD*} $line] } {
                puts $line

        } else {
            puts $output_file $line
    }
}
close $input_file
close $output_file
```

Comment: I wouldn't ask questions with path names like `/india/proj_n16_hbm2etigris/n16_hbm2etigris/be/work/ksantosh/innovus/scripts/` in the question.   Looks like it's revealing a project name for your company, or at least an IP name.   It's not necessary to include such a specific path name when asking the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you need command line arguments. You may define your command format like this:

```
def_file.tcl <input_def> <x_offset> <y_offset> [<output_def>]
```

Where <output_def> is optional. In you tcl script file, add the following code:

```
if { $argc < 3 } {
  puts "Usage: $argv0 <input_def> <x_offset> <y_offset> \[<output_def>\]"
  exit
}
lassign $argv input_def x_offset y_offset output_def
if { [string length $output_def] == 0 } {
  set output_filename [file rootname $input_def]_modified.[file extension $input_def]
}
```

Comment: this is command in command prompt `tclsh prac.tcl def_file.def 20 20`
i added your lines to my code but its executing like this

Comment: `tclsh prac.tcl def_file.def 20 20                                               
Enter input file name:                                       
def_file.def                                                          
Enter offset_x:                                        
3                            
Enter offset_y:                         
3                                     
can't read "input_file": no such variable                      
    while executing                                   
"close $input_file"                                        
    (file "prac.tcl" line 43)`

Comment: 1. Since we are getting variable values from command line, we don't need "gets stdin" any more.
2. Change the "close $input_file" to "close $input_def".